# column filter in datatables

Tags: php, datatables

I am implementing datatables plugin, In my page, Individual column should be filtered.I am trying to implement by following the following link:

```
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
```

But it is not working. Is there any file that I have to include? Even I added `<tfoot>` also.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
           "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "bSortable":false,"aTargets": [XXX]
        }
        });
    } );
```

Where `XXX` is the column number (starting with the first column = 0) you wish to be sorted.

See the [documentation](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns) for more details.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as the solution.  Thank you!